# clear a list, all class values are gone

Tags: c#, list, class

```
class Class2
{
    public string ven;
    public List<string> lname = new List<string>();
}
List<Class2> l = new List<Class2>();
List<string> lhs = new List<string>();

Class2 c2 = new Class2();
c2.ven = line_split[0];
c2.lname = lhs;

l.Add(c2);
lhs.Clear();
```

When `lhs.Clear()` is executed , it empty out object `l`.

What is my alternative?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: And what else do you expect after a List.Clear() call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want clearing `lhs` to clear the list stored on an object, you have to copy the list when assigning it to your object's field:

```
c2.lname = new List<string>(lhs);
```

Ideally you'd be doing this in `Class2`'s constructor.

Answer (score 1):

lhs and the lname variables point to the same `List<string>` object. So, when you clear lhs, it's natural that lname also gets cleared (they point to the same object!)

If you don't want this behavior, copy it to your class field: `c2.lname = new List<string>(lhs)`